# Windows 8.1 upgrade created a second recovery partition. Can I remove the original?

Tags: upgrade, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 upgrade created a second recovery partition. Can I remove the original?

Prior to this the partitions were Recovery, EFI, OS(C:), Data(D:).
After the upgrade partitions  are Recovery, EFI, OS(C:), Recovery, Data(D:).
The first Recovery partition is 1023MB the second is 350MB

The "Create a system image" tool selects the EFI, OS(C:),
and the second 350MB Recovery partitions.
The first 1023MB Recovery partition is not listed, I have to "assume" it is now redundant.

The factory (HP) Recovery Partition was removed using the HP
provided tool after creating recovery disks, and the D: partition created months ago.

Answer (score 0):

given the size difference 1023 VS 350 there is no way the smaller recovery can contain everything.. Also windows 8 and 8.1 recovery is sneaky in that restoring installed apps ONLY restores apps from the MS Store ( where MS got a cut of the purchase price ) APPLICATIONS ( where MS Store did not get a cut ) are not restored..

if you ever have to recover from a failed HD an actual disk image will be much better IMHO
there is still "windows 7 disk imaging" hidden in wimdows 8. just google how to find it alternatively
free "EaseUs ToDo Backup Free" which does incremental backups as well